# Convergence of the product of i.i.d radom variables with uniform distribution on $[0,2]$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and $(X_n)$ i.i.d. random variables with uniform distribution on $[0,2]$. If $Y_n=X_1\ldots X_n$, is there convergence in any mode of $Y_n$?

I start by taking $\Omega=[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$ equipped with the product of the infinite product of the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and let $X_n:(x_k)_k \mapsto 2x_n$. But I find even this special case is hard to deal with.

Comment: Anyone please explain the reason for "off-topic" vote? I am reading the solution... I don't see why this is not a well-defined question...

Answer (score 0):

Note that $Elog X_n =\frac 1 2 \int_0^{2} log \, x \, dx=log \, 2 -1$. By SLLN $ \frac 1 n{log \, Y_n} =\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^{n} log \,  X_i \to log \, 2 -1 <0$. Hence $log \, Y_n \to -\infty$ with probability $1$ and $Y_n \to 0$ with probability $1$.